# How to Use com.facebook.fresco and com.parse:parse-android without confilicting each other?

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle, fresco

I'm quite new to gradle with android studio. I'm building a project and was using fresco to load images to my Android application. Now i need to intergrate push notifications service so decided to use parse. But When I was trying to Intergrate parse I got an Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

Here after searching a bit I found out that Fresco library and Parse libary both use bolts. So i excluded bolts-android from Fresco and now I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

So how can I use both Fresco Library and Parse Library together in my android application? My gradle build file is as below:

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.osmium.ykb"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    }
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3'
}
```

My dependencies were like this when checked with './gradlew app:dependencies'

```
_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure #
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9
|    \--- cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.3.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0
+--- com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0
+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.8.1
|    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.8.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.8.1
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.8.1
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.8.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
\--- com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3
     \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1 -> 23.1.1 (*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding  little bit more I found the answer. Just had to add

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Sorry. I misunderstood this as a package conflict issue. But seems it was an issue with the size.

Answer (score 2):

You should exclude bolts-taks and not bolts-android, try this:

```
compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1'){
     exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-tasks';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Then maybe try excluding bolts-android from the parse library and compiling the whole fresco library like this:

```
compile ('com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'){
     exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android';
}
```

Comment: if i remove 'bolts-tasks' i get the error saying 
'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class'

Comment: Actually i removed that coz it does not contain 'bolts-tasks' but 'bolts-android' gradle The dependencies are like this for fresco

+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.8.1
|    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.8.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.8.1
etc

Answer (score 1):

Use them with the these versions:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this question, but can't find or don't wanna find it.

**here**: remove this line , and you are good to go.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: removed it but still getting the same error :(

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3